# Get permanent residency in Canada while working remotely for a non-Canadian company

Tags: visa, canada

I am considering moving to Canada (British Columbia to be specific if that matters) long-term with my family, but I can't figure out what the best way to get permanent residency for myself and my family is.

The legal situation is, I am a Swedish national, my wife is a Japanese national, and we have two small children who have Swedish/Japanese dual citizenship, and we currently reside in Japan.

I work remotely for a Swedish company. I make enough to support the whole family, and would like to continue working remotely for said company after moving. I do not have a university education, if that matters.

What would you say is the best way for me and my family to get permanent residency (or the equivalent legal status where you can live and work indefinitely) in Canada?

Comment: Does your wife have income from labour, and/or does she intend to have income from labour after the intended relocation?

Comment: Start here: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/crs-tool.asp There are other options too but this is the easiest one IMO.